# Under which conditions on a Markov process $X$ does $\frac 1t\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\operatorname P_x\left[X_t\in B\right]$ exist?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let

- $I\subseteq[0,\infty)$ be closed under addition and $0\in I$
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space
- $E$ be a Polish space and $\mathcal E$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $E$
- $X=(X_t)_{t\in I}$ be a stochastic process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ with values in $(E,\mathcal E)$
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in I}$ be the filtration generated by $X$

$X$ is called a **Markov process** with distributions $(\operatorname P_x)_{x\in E}$ $:\Leftrightarrow$

1. $\operatorname P_x$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ with $$\operatorname P_x\left[X_0=x\right]=1\;,$$ For all $x\in E$
2. $\kappa : E\times\mathcal E^{\otimes I}\to[0,1]$ with $$\kappa(x,A):=\operatorname P_x\left[X\in A\right]$$ is a stochastic kernel
3. $X$ has the *weak Markov property*, i.e. $$\operatorname P_x\left[X_{s+t}\in B\mid\mathcal F_s\right]=\kappa_t(X_s,B)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in E\;s,t\in I\;\text{and }B\in\mathcal E\;\tag 1$$ where $$\kappa_t:E\times\mathcal E\to[0,1]\;,\;\;\;(x,B)\mapsto\kappa\left(x,\left\{y\in E^I:y(t)\in B\right\}\right)=\operatorname P_x\left[X_t\in B\right]$$

> **Question**:$\;\;\;$Let $x\in E$ and $B\in\mathcal E$. Under which conditions does $$q(x,B):=\frac 1t\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\kappa_t(x,B)$$ exist?

Probably, we need at least right-continuity of $X$, but I'm unsure which further assumptions we need in detail.

Comment: @saz I'm sorry, I've made a mistake in phrasing the question. I'm not interested in the existence of $$\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\operatorname P_x\left[X_t\in B\right]\;,$$ but $$\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\frac 1t\operatorname P_x\left[X_t\in B\right]\;.$$ I assume that's an important difference, since (for $x\in E$) $$\mu_t:=\frac 1t\operatorname P_x\left[X_t\in\;\cdot\;\right]\;\;\;\text{for }t\in I\setminus\left\{0\right\}$$ is not a family of (sub-)probability measures anymore.

Comment: If you take $B=E$ then $q(x,E)=\infty$.  Is that a problem?

Comment: @NateEldredge Is your comment related to my previous one? In general: No, that's not a problem. As you may guess, I'm especially interested in the question: "Under which conditions does the so called *$Q$-matrix* exist?" In that special scenario, one assumes $E$ to be countable and $I=[0,\infty)$. And the sets $B$ of interest are $B=\left\{y\right\}$ for $y\in E$. However, I've asked myself how restrictive we really need to be in general.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I see. So far, I've seen these kind of results only for (real-valued) Lévy processes and, more generally, Feller processes.

Comment: @saz Do you know, that $$q(x,y):=\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\frac 1t\operatorname P_x\left[X_t=y\right]\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in E$$ ($E$ assumed to be at most countable) is the so-called *transition rate matrix* (or *$Q$-matrix*) and is considered in "continuous-time Markov chains"? I'm working with the textbook *Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course* (see link below for the relevant chapter) and the author introduces this matrix without stating under which conditions $q$ exists.

Comment: Link to the relevant chapter of *Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course*: https://books.google.de/books?id=xDy3BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA362&lpg=PA362&dq=%22klenke%22+%2B+%22discrete+markov+processes%22&source=bl&ots=u6VfjudspJ&sig=eSiYb64HqenAuS0FB78y4s6subs&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMIlpiG3uOryAIVwr4UCh3eAg9A#v=onepage&q=%22klenke%22%20%2B%20%22discrete%20markov%20processes%22&f=false

Comment: No, sorry, I'm not familiar with continuous-time Markov chains.

Comment: *There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.*

Comment: @Did I need to disagree. If you relax the assumptions and let $E$ be at most countable and $I=[0,\infty)$, then this is exactly the setting of the transition rate matrix (which is considered in continuous-time, discrete Markov processes) I've got in mind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain#Infinitesimal_definition